# wrap table in a div

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="panelBelow">
     <div id="moveLeftDown">
          <p>table here</p>
     </div>
</div>

#panelBelow
    {
        width:100%;
        height:30px;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        margin-top:15px;
    }
```

Is it possible to put a table there instead of the table here text, but have it so the table wraps to the width of the div. I should add that there is padding on my body css too.

```
body
    {
        font-family:HelveticaNeue-Light;
        font-size:14px;
        padding:20px;
        background-color:#808080;
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can put the table there.

Comment: How can I get it to wrap? so scale the cells in x amount of columns depending on the div width?

Comment: So, you want to dynamically call a fluid number of columns? You would need javascript or jquery to determine the number of columns you would need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put table inside indicated DIV. You would have problem only if you have very lengthy word like: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh".

You can come over that using word-break and your table never extends the parent div.

```
<div id="panelBelow">
     <div id="moveLeftDown">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>Hello world!</td>
                  <td>Goes a long sentence</td>
                  <td>andyoumightbeafraidofthis</td>
                  <td>actions</td>
              </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>

body
    {
        font:normal 14px Arial;
        padding:20px;
        background-color:#808080;
    }

#panelBelow
    {
        width:300px;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        margin-top:15px;
    }

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

td{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:5px 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
    word-break:break-word;
}
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/ej2RD/